# wordpress ajax Call to upload file

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

i am trying to upload file using ajax in wordpress.

i am trying following form:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="file_form">

<?php  wp_nonce_field("ajax_file_nonce","security");  
 wp_localize_script( 'custom-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
 ?>

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="my_file_upload">
<input id="resume" name="resume" class="input-file form-control" type="file">
```

here is my function:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_file_upload', 'my_file_upload');

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_file_upload', 'my_file_upload');

function handle_file_upload()
{

    $response['message'] = 'Done!';
     echo json_encode($response); die();
     check_ajax_referer('ajax_file_nonce', 'security');

    if(!(is_array($_POST) && is_array($_FILES) && defined('DOING_AJAX') && DOING_AJAX)){
        return;
    }

    if(!function_exists('wp_handle_upload')){
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    }
    $upload_overrides = array('test_form' => false);

    $response = array();

    foreach($_FILES as $file){
        $file_info = wp_handle_upload($file, $upload_overrides);

        // do something with the file info...
        $response['message'] = 'Done!';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    die();
}
```

here is my jquery:

```
jQuery(document).on(\'click\', \'#send\', function(e){
//alert();
e.preventDefault();
var ajax_url = "'.admin_url('admin-ajax.php').'"
    var form_data = {};
$("#file_form").find(\'input\').each(function(){
    form_data[this.name] = $(this).val();
    //alert(this.name);
    });


jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: MyAjax.ajaxurl, // 
        data: form_data,
        contentType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
            alert(response.message);
        }
    }); 


 });
```

but this shows MyAjax not defined. when i tried "ajax_url" variable defined in same jquery, it return "undefined" message.

what is the problem in this code ? what modifications are needed. help me please.

Comment: i have tried to find all the example and also tried everything. they suggested. but don't know what i am missing.

Comment: i got no success with this but i found this plugin and customized for my use. https://wordpress.org/plugins/alchemist-ajax-upload/ thanks to the developer..

Answer (score 3):

It probably depends on how you load your jQuery script and how you use the `wp_localize_script` function.

Try this in your *functions.php* file:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-ajax-request', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/custom-ajax-request.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'custom-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
} );
```

The `wp_enqueue_script` function load your jQuery script (I named the file `custom-ajax-request.js`) and `wp_localize_script` pass the *MyAjax* variable to the script (make sure you use the same handle, in this case `'custom-ajax-request'`).

Also you should unquote the strings in your jQuery script, and remove the `wp_localize_script` row from the form in your template file.

Comment: error solved :  "MyAjax is not defined ". but return 0,not returning "Done!".

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
contentType: 'json'
```

from jquery and give a try.

i have read somewhere in previous stack answers

Comment: it works but when i tried to print $_files array, it shows empty. what should i do ?